# How to order ascending the variables a , b , c?

Tags: c++

How to order ascending the variables a , b , c?   (in a simpler way)

```
void Crescator(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int z = (a > b) ? a : b;
    if(z < c)
    {
        cout << a << c << b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite way; hopefully self-explanatory

`if (a > c) std::swap(a, c);`

`if (a > b) std::swap(a, b);`

`if (b > c) std::swap(b, c);`

Don't forget to pass the parameters to `Crescator` *by reference* if you want to make them sorted in the caller.